# How is a potential divider able to reduce current to zero?

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, voltage

For example, a filament lamp, in series with a uniform resistive wire, can have its voltage varied by moving the sliding contact, e.g., a rotatable wheel. 
However, why is a potential divider able to reduce the current to zero, but a variable resistor in series with the filament lamp cannot reduce current to zero?

Answer (score 2):

A standard sort of potential divider has a slider which can travel from one end and produce a maximum potential across its output terminals and hence to the circuit under investigation and then when the slider is at the other end the voltage across its output terminals is zero and hence as no voltage is supplied to the circuit under investigation no current will flow in that circuit assuming there are no other voltage or current sources present.

---

**Later**

[image]

For the potential divider I have made the assumption $R\gg R_1,R_2$ only to make the sums easier.
Even if that condition was not satisfied the potential divider could still have an output voltage of zero when $R_2$ is zero.

For the series resistor you can make the current zero by breaking the circuit.  However if had a complete circuit and $R_3$ was very large there would still be a current flowing.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however this still doesn't explain why a potential divider is able to produce zero voltage whereas a variable resistor is not.

Comment: @John I have added to my answer.

Comment: Thanks again. I now understand the circuit with the variable resistor, however for the potential divider, surely the only way to get 0 current through R2 would be for the resistance of R2 to equal 0 - which is iimpossible.

Comment: Also, [this](http://m.imgur.com/DKUUu4Z) is the example used in the textbook. If the current into the filament lamp, I2 = (VR2)/(R1+R2) * 1/R2, where R2 is the filament lamp and R1 the resistive wire, for the current to be zero does this not assume that R2 is zero?